# How to configure AWS Elemental MediaLive regarding the cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-live

If the resolution is 1080P, how much does it cost if 10000 viewers watch the live stream for 1 hour?

Comment: its better you consult an aws sales rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options :

MediaLive plus S3 plus CloudFront is one valid workflow if you don't need DASH formats or Encryption.  Each service in the workflow has its own line item in the combined price.

MediaLive plus MediaPackage plus CloudFront is the high-end workflow most often chosen by media professionals. It provides multi-format streaming (creating DASH + CMAF automatically for example), and provides optional Encryption and optional Ad Insertion via MediaTailor. Each service in the workflow has its own line item in the combined price.

The AWS Interactive Video Service (IVS) offers "twitch-quality" 1080P HLS streaming at attractive prices with very fast easy configuration. This would be a one-stop shop solution with simplified pricing.

To answer your question you can look at the public pricing guides, or start a conversation with an AWS salesperson via the web form at: https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/sales-support/

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elemental MediaLive is a Live encoder and it does not serve the content to viewers. In order to serve the video content to viewer, you have to output the video to an origin server such as AWS S3 or AWS Elemental MediaPackage. If you have 10,000 viewers, it is advised to use CloudFront when streaming the content.

AWS Elemental MediaLive is charged on a fixed rate base on the combination of codec, bitrate, and resolution of the input stream and output stream. Detail of the pricing can be found here:
https://aws.amazon.com/medialive/pricing/